# How to modify existing keyboard layout (RU, kbdru.dll)?

Tags: windows, keyboard-layout

There's a program I'm thinking of using called [Punto Switcher](http://punto.yandex.ru/mac/) that detects a language I'm typing in and switching entire word between Russian and English. The problem I have with this setup is that even though most of Russian letters "correspond" to English letters, Russian keys are scattered all over the keyboard and I don't feel like learning them all as I type in English mostly.

Now, the program is very specific about me using RU, `kbdru.dll` file, not any other and if I use a custom keyboard under Russian, it doesn't recognize what I type so I think I should change the default RU keyboard.

I created my custom keyboard using Microsoft's tool and I need to modify original one. I think it will take more than just replacing a file.

Help?

Answer (score 1):

Make your layout and follow the steps to create a binary-installation file. You don't need to manually move `.dll` files around. Just install the layout and select it from the localization/keyboard menu in the Control Panel.

Use the [Microsoft Keyboard Layout Creator (MSKLC)](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=21476), and see [this ZIP archive](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/45770266/rusnor-genja.org.zip) for an example of a working Russian phonetic layout (it matches a Norwegian keyboard, which is like the English with the exception of keys like `{}()[]/.,` and so on).

Comment: The program ignores languages other than RU. I tried adding one but program wouldn't recognize it.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a keyboard layout .dll file, you can always replace the system standard layout with your own.  Simply place your layout file in the \Windows\system32 directory.  Open registry by running regedit.exe.  Scroll to **HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Control\Keyboard Layouts**.  Layout number **00000419** is for Russian, number **00010419** is for Russian Typewriter, and **00020419** is for Russian Mnemonic (transliterated, kinda).  There are other layouts for other languages, so you can pretty much change any of them.  Each of these folders will contain several entries.  The one you want to modify is Layout File.  By double-clicking it you can edit and change the layout DLL to whatever your custom layout file is.  You can also rename it to your own layout by changing the Layout Text entry, but that it not necessary, as long as you remember which layout is now your own custom.